# Как добавить шорткод в заголовок категории Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне нужно добавить шорткод в заголовок категории Woocomerce, но при добавлении он не отрабатывает, на прямую в коде прописать шорткод не получится, так как сайт на конструкторе WP Bakery, заголовок там подтягивается из заголовка категории.
Тема Impreza.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]